# How to get modified values from controller to custom directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have defined one variable in controller and i have assigned this value to one attribute of custom directive. So on the basis of this value i am showing the modal box template. Now if i click on the cancel button from modal box template then it calls one function from controller which is modifying the variable value to false but it is not hiding the popup box. Please help me to fix it.

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('module1').directive('myDirective', function () {
    function linkFunction(scope, elem, attrs) {
        //scope.openvalue   = attrs.openvalue;
        scope.closevalue = false;
        scope.close = function () {
            console.log("Inside Close");
            scope.openvalue = false;
            scope.closevalue = false;
        };
    };

    return {
        templateUrl: 'confirmTemplate.html',
        restrict: 'E',
        link: linkFunction,
        scope: {
            confirmtext: '@',
            openvalue: '=',
            closeconfirm: '&',
            submitconfirm: '&'
        },
        controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.$watch('openvalue', function () {
                console.log("OpenValue : " + $scope.openvalue);
            });
        }]
    };
 });
})();
```

Following is the html for opening this modal.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 options" ng-click="cntrl.flag1 = true">
  <div class="row">
    <myDirective openvalue="cntrl.flag1" confirmtext="This is the text from directive"
                 closeconfirm="cntrl.closeconfirm()" submitconfirm="cntrl.submitconfirm()"></myDirective>
    <div class="col-xs-9 no-left-right-padding">My text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And i want the updated value of openvalue inside html template but it is not working.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? It would be useful to see the associated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be more clear to have you codes here, but I think the problem is when you call the function from controller, it doesn't actually modify the variable of **controller scope** but **modal's scope**.

In AngularJS scope, any change of inherited variable in child scope will create a local version.

Based on your words, when you open a modal window it will create a new child scope and when you call the function from controller to modify that scope variable, you actually modifying that child scope variable not controller's.

You can simply add `console.log($scope.$id);` in controller and the function then you should be able to see the scope id is different.

This [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yd3bv80u/) will give you the idea, press `Esc` key to close the modal window. However, as I said it would be better to have your code to address exact issue.

---

Based on your code, a quick fix is assign the `cntrl` object into directive which will make sure your directive refer to the same object.

Change your modal to

```
<myDirective cntrl="cntrl" confirmtext="This is the text from directive"></myDirective>
```

in your directive

```
scope: {
    confirmtext   : '@',
    cntrl     : '='
},
```

in your linkFunction

```
function linkFunction(scope, elem, attrs){
    scope.close = function(){
        scope.cntrl.flag1 = false;
    }
```

you still can access `closeconfirm` and `submitconfirm` by `$scope.cntrl.closeconfirm` and `$scope.cntrl.submitconfirm` respectively.

Comment: Ohh it means we can modify controller values inside directive too

Comment: If you pass in `cntrl` and make sure you don't change the object reference in directive, then yes you can manipulate the properties (values) of `cntrl` inside directive as you want.

Comment: Actually, it is successfully manipulating the value of flag1 to false but later it is changing itself

Comment: I have written watch function so there it is showing that the value is converting to true but the later it is converting to false.

Comment: what is `ng-click="cntrl.flag1 = true"` used for? It's really hard to tell from the code snippet your provided here, can you put it on jsfiddle? Btw, if you think the original problem was solved, would be good you can give a vote then I can have right to comment and help more people. Thx.

Comment: Yaa the value of flag1 is modifying into false but ut is not reflecting into template

Comment: If you can copy & paste your code to this JSFiddle and make sure it works, then click `Fork` then paste me the link, it would be easier to get your problem solve.

Comment: Actually, i can not paste that code there. Thank you for helping me.